# unknown command 'migrate' - run command in python

Tags: python, django, shell

I have written this little python script which should `cd` into my django project, activate the virtualenv and start local dev

```
import os
import subprocess
os.chdir('C:\workspace\mysite_env\Scripts')
subprocess.call('activate', shell=True)
os.chdir('C:\workspace\mysite_env\mysite')
subprocess.call('fab run_backend', shell=True)
```

the problem is:

I want this script to be on my desktop,  and there is a command `python manage.py migrate` in my fabric file, in function `run_backend`,

in this function, i have `python manage.py migrate` where this script is failing with:

`unknown command 'migrate'`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is that the entire script? Is that script `manage.py`? That script doesn't use its arguments anywhere (unless `subprocess` does that automagically) so I'm not sure how that could be coming from that run.

Comment: the code above is in my script called ``start_dev.py`` on desktop. the command ``python manage.py migrate`` is in my fabric function called ``run_backend``

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the `python` in `python manage.py migrate`. This python is likely not the same as the one you use after `activate`.

You should do the same call to `activate` in the `run_backend` function as well.